# Prevent Google Analytics from tracking entire URL. GA is ignoring page_path and I am not trying to block URL variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I specify page_path when submitting to Google Analytics. I do this because I do not want Google Analytics tracking the entire URL. Here is my code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*********-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

    gtag("js", new Date());
    gtag("config", "UA-*********-1", {

    "custom_map": {
        "dimension4": "NODE",
        "dimension5": "USER_TYPE",
    }
    , "page_path":"/user/edit"
});

    gtag("event", "page_view", {"NODE": "user/edit"}); 
    gtag("event", "page_view", {"USER_TYPE": "footballer"}); 
</script>
```

However, when I create a custom Widget and select Dimension "Page" I can see the entire URL of pages visited. How can I stop this?

For example, if the URL is, "https://my_site.com/user/edit/protected_info" I only want "/user/edit" going to Google Analytics. I am using CodeIgniter, which uses URL variables as the path.

Comment: You probably have a filter set for the view that merges the hostname with the page dimension.

Comment: There are no filters set, it is the default GA setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case page_path used in the GA4 - Configuration Tag in GTM overwrites the  dp (document path) parameter in the URL request to google-analytics.com.

Another thing that you can do, as there are not so much documentation about this parameters name conventions except the reserved ones, is to create a custom dimension called path_clean and then you can reuse them your way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).